# Prove: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n\sin{n^3}}{3^{n-1}+3n}=3$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n\sin{n^3}}{3^{n-1}+3n}=3$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^{n-1}+3n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^n\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3n}{3^n}\right)}=3$$

How evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n^3$?

Comment: I am pretty sure the limit you are trying to find does not exist.

Comment: $\sin n^3$ fluctuates between $-1$ and $1$, keep in mind that it is periodic. So to conclude, its limit to infinity simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Does that mean the equation is not true?

Comment: @user_99 It isn't an equation to begin with. If you're asking whether $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{3^n\sin n^3}{3^{n-1}+3n}=3$ is correct, then the answer is no.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n^3$ does not exist, the sequence oscillate between -1 and 1. The rest converge to 3 as you said. The whole sequence has infinitely many accumulation points.

Comment: While undoubtedly the limit of $\sin(n^3)$ does not exist, *proving* it might be not particularly simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two sequences
$$a_n=\sqrt[3]{\pi n} \to\infty$$
$$b_n=\sqrt[3]{2\pi n+\tfrac2\pi}\to\infty$$

For your sequence $s(n)$, you have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s(a_n)=0$$

because $\sin({a_n}^3)=0$, and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s(b_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{b_n}}{3^{b_n-1}+3b_n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac13+\frac{3b_n}{3^{b_n}}}=3$$

because $\sin({b_n}^3)=1$ and $\lim \frac{3b_n}{3^{b_n}}=0$. It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s(n)$ does not exist.